# How is the JF (Jam Factor) in the respond of traffic flow calculated? Is the real-time volume considered?

Tags: here-api

I am using the traffic flow REST API provided by HERE map. In our project, we need to get the information of the real-time traffic flow. In the respond of the traffic flow request, there is one item called JF (Jam Factor), which might fit our need. However, we have to confirm how the JF is calculated, or at least if the real-time vehicle volume considered in the calculation. The following link is an example of such request and corresponding respond: 
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-proximity

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[Obtaining Traffic Tiles](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/tiles.html) might contain information you want. Specifically, the page has a table that says

> Table 1. Traffic Flow to Color Mapping

```
| Color  | Description                                             |
|--------|---------------------------------------------------------|
| Green  | Free flow of traffic: 0 <= JAM_FACTOR < 4               |
| Yellow | Sluggish flow of traffic: 4 <= JAM_FACTOR < 8           |
| Red    | Slow flow of traffic: 8 <= JAM_FACTOR < 10              |
| Black  | Traffic stopped flowing or road closed: JAM_FACTOR = 10 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I'd like to confirm is whether the calculation of Jam Factor takes traffic flow/volume into account.

Comment: @JiaGuoI am afraid that information is not available publicly, but you can perhaps write them an email and ask them.